# Why are half of my <hr>s being styled differently than the others?

Tags: css

I don't know why, but when I try and style my horizontal rules in css, every other hr looks different. See below:

https://i.imgur.com/ltZdncM

When I increase the border size to 2px, the gap in between the top and bottom borders is filled in, but then half the horizontal rules are thicker than the others.

MY CODE:

```css
hr {
    border: 1px solid #07234f;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <hr>
    </body>
```

I expect all the horizontal rules to look similar. Any idea why they look different? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6):

You're placing a border on all sides of the `hr`. But Chrome, for example, already has a user-agent stylesheet that sets an inset border style on `hr`'s. I was able to replicate your issue at various `px` units.

One way to fix this issue is the following:

1. kill whatever border the user agent stylesheet may be implementing behind your back: `border: 0`
2. Then set a border along a single edge (top or bottom) and set it to the `px` value you'd like. (I chose `border-top: 2px`.)
3. Set an explicit height on the `hr` equal to the pixel value you chose for `border-top` to prevent (in this case) Chrome's user agent stylesheet from displaying `border-style: inset` on your element.

```css
hr {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #07234f;
    height: 2px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <hr>
    </body>
```

Another approach might be to explicitly set the individual `border` properties yourself so as to avoid confusing Chrome about which border style to apply (it appears that even with `border: 1px solid #000000`, Chrome still insists on applying the `inset` styling).

```
    hr {
        border-width: 2px 0 0 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color:  #07234f;
        width: 300px;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

One way to implement a double line would be to set a top and bottom border with an explicit height:

```
    hr {
        border-width: 2px 0 2px 0;
        height: 4px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color:  #07234f;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 16px auto;
    }
```

You could also use `border-style: double` like this:

```
    hr {
        border-width: 4px 0 0 0;
        border-style: double;
        border-color:  #07234f;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 16px auto;
    }
```

Also, here's some inspiration for your `hr` styling needs: https://css-tricks.com/simple-styles-for-horizontal-rules/

It's a bit dated, but may give you some ideas.

**UPDATE 2**

This works fairly well, though I do still see some aberrations at various zoom levels. Does the following work for you at normal zoom? Is it only when you manually zoom the viewport that you see aberrations?

It's a conundrum.

```
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  height: 2px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='300' height='2' viewBox='0 0 376 2' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E %3Cline y1='0.5' x2='300' y2='0.5' stroke='black' stroke-opacity='0.1'/%3E %3Cline y1='1.5' x2='300' y2='1.5' stroke='white' stroke-opacity='0.3'/%3E %3C/svg%3E ");
}
```

Comment: What if I'd like to set a border on the top and bottom to add more depth and style the the hr?

Comment: I've updated my answer, @DirectCherry. See if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I did a poor job of explaining how I wanted to use a top and bottom border. I'm looking to do something like hr.style-six (from the link you sent). When I use the code provided for that style, it works. However, if I change the color, I get the same weird error I've been dealing with. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you link to a fiddle/pen or attach a screenshot of the weird error? Not sure how to debug without it.

Comment: I take that back. The problem persists even when I simply copy and paste the code from the website. Here's 2 screenshots. I did style 2 and six. I did not change the colors. https://imgur.com/a/YHv08Lt EDIT: Is it possible its a rendering error? I zoomed in on the default <hr>s in Chrome (without any user-defined styling) and the styling is inconsistent with them as well.

Comment: Hmm. I am not able to replicate the rendering bug on my particular setup. 
https://imgur.com/cvz2STR

There may be a different way to accomplish this effect, though, without the weird rendering issue. Looking into it.