# <hr> tags showing different behaviour

Tags: html, css

When I'm using `<hr>` tags to create horizontal rows then the behavior is **not uniform** i.e. all the `<hr>`s (in my case) are displaying **alternate background color**.

Also, I've tested in **Chrome and opera** and the **zoom level was 100%** at the time of testing.

For reference, below is the image:-

[image]

```css
hr{
    border-style: none;
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.253) ;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
```

Comment: What is the problem?!! It shows as it should.

Comment: Check this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554149/why-are-half-of-my-hrs-being-styled-differently-than-the-others

Comment: Check My solution I think that was relative error

Answer (score 0):

Try use relative units like EM instead of PX, it magically works.

```css
hr{
    border-style: none;
    width: 10%;
    height: 0.1rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.253) ;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
```

You can use https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_pxtoemconversion.asp to convert PX to EM. Using relative units make your site more user-friendly to most of the displays.

Answer (score 0):

```css
hr{
        width: 80px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.253) ;
    }
```

```html
<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
```

Don't Use height in percentage it is kind of giving relative values.

Maybe Your HTML hr tags are inheriting styles from somewhere else from your style sheet. That's the reason maybe they are Loading like this.
Try to inspect those hr from chromedev tools.

Comment: This is supposed to be not related to its parents or root, cuz as you see, even in the clean snippet, it is still not fixed. I would prefer to see it as a default UA rendering setting, or sth else about rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Turn `background-color:transparent` and `border:0` - to remove default properties as set by browser, and use either of (border-top, border-bottom) to have consistant height. Also, refer to: [Why are half of my <hr>s being styled differently than the others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55554149/why-are-half-of-my-hrs-being-styled-differently-than-the-others)

```css
hr{
    border:0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
<br>

<hr>
```